# Python: how to update a csv file from another csv file

Tags: python, csv

We have two CSV files: `a.csv` and `b.csv`.

`a.csv` has tree columns: *label*, *item1*, *item2*. `b.csv` has two columns: *item1*, *item2*. If *item1* and *item2* in `a.csv` also occurr in `b.csv`, that's `a.csv` and `b.csv` have same *item1* and *item2*, the value of *label* in `a.csv` should be *1* instead.

For example:

`a.csv`:

```
label    item1     item2
0         123       35
0         342       721
0         876       243
```

`b.csv`:

```
item1     item2
 12        35
 32        721
 876       243
```

`result.csv`:

```
label    item1     item2
0         123       35
0         342       721
1         876       243
```

Comment: The result can be write in a new csv file "result.csv"

Comment: What did you try yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your `a.csv` into a dictionary; use a tuple of `(item1, item2)` as the key. Then when reading `b.csv` you can update the label for each entry in the dictionary as you process the file.

After this process, write out `result.csv` from the information in the dictionary.

```
import csv

rows = {}
with open('a.csv', 'r', newline='') as acsv:
    areader = csv.DictReader(acsv)
    for row in reader:
        # store the row based on the item1 and item2 columns
        key = (row['item1'], row['item2'])
        rows[key] = row

with open('b.csv', 'r', newline='') as bcsv:
    breader = csv.DictReader(bcsv)
    for row in reader:
        # set the label of matching rows to 1 when present
        key = (row['item1'], row['item2'])
        if key in rows:
            rows[key]['label'] = 1

with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as result:
    writer = csv.DictReader(result, fieldnames=areader.fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(rows.values())
```

I used [`csv.DictReader()` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to ease column name handling. Each row is presented as a dictionary, with the keys taken from the first row in the CSV file.

I also assumed you are using Python 3; if you are using Python 2, you'll have to adjust the `open()` calls to remove the `newline=''` argument, and you need to use binary mode (`'rb'` and `'wb'`). I did not specify a codec for the files; currently the default system codec will be used to read and write. If that is incorrect, add `encoding='...'` arguments.

Comment: I'm not expecting any dict. the `label` is header from the csv file, and I have the same case. But not working.

Comment: @Syafiqur__: then my guess would be that you wanted to use `rows['label']`, not `rows[key]['label']`.  Again, no code, no [mcve], so all I can do is guess. And I'm sorry, but you are not helping me improve _this_ answer, so the comments here are not appropriate.